# How to get a Yii2 GridView Column to put NULL values at the end for both sort orders?

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I have a column of data that has some numeric values but occasionally has NULL values in it, e.g.:

```
Name    Algebra   Band  Chemistry
Abel     3         6        2
Baker    5         NULL     4
Charlie  NULL      2        NULL
Delta    4         NULL     NULL
```

Is it possible to make a sort object so that in both directions of Score, the NULL values are always at the end?  That is,

```
Name    Algebra [asc]  Band     Chemistry
Abel     3              6        2
Delta    4              NULL     NULL
Baker    5              NULL     4
Charlie  NULL           2        NULL

Name    Algebra [desc]  Band     Chemistry
Baker    5              NULL     4
Delta    4              NULL     NULL
Abel     3              6        2
Charlie  NULL           2        NULL
```

EDIT:  I should add a clarification here -- I'm using ArrayDataProvider because this is a summary table, so I can't do anything that is on the database side -- the data is already loaded into a local array and there are no more database queries.

EDIT2: I've got a request for some code and some more about the structure I'm using.  So, I've edited the examples above to be a bit closer to my actual situation.  The source data looks something like this:

```
[MySQL table and Yii model "Scores"]
Name     Class         Score
Abel     Algebra        3
Abel     Band           6
Abel     Chemistry      2
Baker    Algebra        5
Baker    Chemistry      4
Charlie  Band           2
Delta    Algebra        4
```

Here's the relevant sections of the code:

```
  $data = [];
  $items = Scores::find()->all();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $data[$item->name]['Name'] = $item->name;
    $data[$item->name][$item->class] = $item->score;
  }
  $arrayData = ArrayHelper::toArray($data);
  $arrayDataProviderInit = [
    'allModels' => $arrayData,
    'pagination' => [
      'pageSize' => 0,
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'attributes' => [
        'Name',
        // WHAT GOES HERE????
      ],
    ],
  ];
  $arrayDataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider($arrayDataProviderInit);
  $gridViewInit = [
    'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
    'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => 'NULL'],
    'columns' => [
        'Name',
        'Algebra',
        'Band',
        'Chemistry',
    ],
  ];
  echo GridView::widget($gridViewInit);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can redefine the sorting rules for a particular attribute by adding a `IS NULL` expression before the actual sort
here's a use-case with ActiveDataProvider's sort object

```
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes = ArrayHelper::merge($dataProvider->sort->attributes, [
        'score' => [
            'asc'  => [
                'IS NULL ' . static::tableName().'score' => SORT_DESC,
                static::tableName(). 'score '=> SORT_ASC
            ],
            'desc' => [
                'IS NULL ' . static::tableName().'score' => SORT_DESC,
                static::tableName(). 'score '=> SORT_DESC
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

essentially every time you sort by score this will generate an expression like

```
ORDER BY IS NULL score DESC, score ASC --or  
ORDER BY IS NULL score DESC, score DESC
```

ensuring you first sort by whether or not a value is null, then sort by actual values

---

#### to address your particular use case:

if using an `ArrayDataProvider` basically you can use the same principle, just need to add another property to your data array, and use that to define your sort rules

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $data[$item->name]['Name'] = $item->name;
  $data[$item->name][$item->class] = $item->score;
  $data[$item->name]['hasScore'] = is_null($item->score);
}

$arrayDataProviderInit = [
  'allModels' => $arrayData,
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 0,
  ],
  'sort' => [
    'attributes' => [
      'Name',
      'Score' => [
        'asc' =>  ['hasScore' => SORT_ASC, 'Score' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['hasScore' => SORT_ASC, 'Score' => SORT_DESC],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately this won't work because this is a summary (pivot) table, so it's in an ArrayDataProvider and I have no database to query.

Comment: @onigame are you initializing the your data provider with actual models or array values? please share some code, like how you create your array data provider. and also you are using GridView to display all of this, correct?

Comment: Thanks for paying attention.  I've shared some code above.  I'm using kartik GridView.

Comment: @onigame updated the answer with array rules, i haven't tested the above, but hope at lest the structure serves as good example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the sort attributes, in defaultOrder use just names of attributes, for example:

```
   defaultOrder => ['score' => SORT_ASC],
```

You should not pass db expressions in default order.